# Reexport a class and its type in a "simpler" way

Tags: typescript

for example:

```
// a.ts
export default class A {...}

// b.ts
export default class B {...}
```

I want to reexport them as a member of module C
and use them in this way(both their type and value are needed):

```
import C from 'c.ts'

let instanceOfA : C.A = new C.A();
let instanceOfB : C.B = new C.B();
```

and I have to write my 'c.ts':

```
// c.ts
import _A from 'a.ts';
import _B from 'b.ts';
module C {
  export const A = _A;
  export type A = typeof _A;
  export const B = _B;
  export type B = typeof _B;
}
export default C;
```

is there a simpler way to do it?

PS: I know it's easier to reexport A, B directly from c and using them like

```
import {A, B} from 'c.ts'
```

or

```
import * as C from 'c.ts'
// C.A
```

I just want to know if there's a better way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest `c.ts` would be

```
export * from './a';
export * from './b';
```

And then you would use it as

```
import {A,B} from './c';
```

## More

Defaults only cause needless confusion. You have `import A from './a'` vs. `import {A} from './c'`.

[I would make them consistent and many *TypeScript* projects do the same](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.md). Pure JavaScript devs don't care as much as refactoring / autocomplete is an idea foreign to them.